# GET http://localhost:4200/api/listOfProducts/products.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

In my Angular2 application the organization of the folders is as below

```
 Project
 |
 +-- file 1
 |    
 +-- api //folder
 |   |  
 |   | +-- listOfProducts //folder
 |          |
            +-- products.json //file 
 +-- src //folder
 |  |  
 +  | +-- app //folder
          | +-- product //folder
                 +-- product.service.ts
                 +-- product-list.component.ts
                 +-- //other files
```

product.service.ts is as below:

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

 import {IProduct} from './product';


 @Injectable()

 export class ProductService{

private _productUrl = 'api/listOfProducts/products.json';
   // here 404 error

constructor(private _http: Http) {}

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {

    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
               .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
               .do(data=>console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
              .catch(this.handleError);

}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server error");
  }

}
```

Now after I run my application I got the following error

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/listOfProducts/products.json 404 (Not
>   Found)

I am aware the problem is that the path directory is typed wrong but I have tried several paths and still could not resolved my problem. The problem is that I have not still the knowledge how the Angular2 read the files. 
From the root and below or from the file you are and above?

Comment: The file is not accessible on the server

Comment: @RomanC How can I do this file accessible on the server?

Comment: I reached here when I got 404. However, its about latest version as on 2022 Feb. I found that I have added "src/api" in angular.json while my server was running. I had to restart the server in order for 404 to vanish.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Organisation your project has nothing to do with it, because files should be accessible from the server. It is important how the structure your *dist* folder looks like. Make sure that *dist* folder (which is located on your live-server) contains your json files. If not, you need to configure webpack.

Personally, I think that better solution is to keep mock-data inside src catalog f.e. with other assets, in this way:

```
src
|
+- app
|
+- assets
  | 
  +- css
  |
  +- img
  |
  +- mock-data
     |
     your.json
```

Comment: K : Your answer is great. In order to do a file accessible on server, json file must be placed inside src/assets

Comment: In fact, it depends on the configuration of webpack :) No problem, bro

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Angular CLI and ng serve to run the angular application, All json files should be under assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Devlopment environment keep All json files under assets folder. otherwise you would get 404 file not found error.